# How to block bot from stealing deposited eth in smart contract

Tags: bots, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I am working on smart contract for a simple payment system where u deposit and get a code. Then u can give a code to anyone and they can withdraw to any address.

I have already tested on all testnets and it works fine.
But on ethereum mainnet as soon as I deposit the eth, it is stolen and transferred by a mev bot.

```js
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

// It will be used by the Solidity compiler to validate its version.
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

// We import this library to be able to use console.log
import "hardhat/console.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract Payment is Ownable {
    address payable public feeWallet;
    uint256 public feeAmount;
    uint256 private numberOfDeposits = 0;

    struct Deposit {
        uint256 time;
        bytes32 id;
        uint256 amount;
    }
    // mapping(address => bytes32[]) public addressToHashes;
    mapping(bytes32 => uint256) public hashToAmount;
    mapping(address => Deposit[]) public addressToDeposits;
    mapping(bytes32 => bool) public isWithdrawn;

    event DepositCreated(address _payer, uint256 _amount);
    event DepositWithdrawn(
        address _withdrawer,
        uint256 _amount,
        address indexed _withdrawTo
    );

    constructor(address _feeWallet) {
        feeWallet = payable(_feeWallet);
    }

    function createDeposit(string memory _id) public payable returns (bytes32) {
        //Check if value is greater than 0
        require(msg.value > 0, "Amount cannot be equal to 0");
        //Fetch mapppings
        Deposit[] storage deposits = addressToDeposits[msg.sender];
        //Create Hash from id
        bytes32 hash = generateId(_id);
        //Update Mappings
        hashToAmount[hash] = msg.value;
        numberOfDeposits += 1;
        deposits.push(Deposit(block.timestamp, hash, msg.value));
        addressToDeposits[msg.sender] = deposits;
        emit DepositCreated(msg.sender, msg.value);
        return hash;
    }

    function generateId(string memory _id) internal view returns (bytes32) {
        uint id = uint(
            keccak256(
                abi.encodePacked(
                    _id,
                    block.difficulty,
                    block.timestamp,
                    numberOfDeposits
                )
            )
        );
        return bytes32(id % 100000000000000);
    }

    function checkDepositExist(uint _id) public view returns (bool) {
        bytes32 hash = bytes32(_id);
        uint256 amount = hashToAmount[hash];
        console.log("amount", amount);
        if (amount > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function viewDeposit(uint _id) public view returns (uint256) {
        bytes32 hash = bytes32(_id);
        uint256 amount = hashToAmount[hash];
        return amount;
    }

    function withdrawDeposit(uint _id, address _to) public {
        require(checkDepositExist(_id), "ID invalid");
        bytes32 hash = bytes32(_id);
        uint256 amount = hashToAmount[hash] - feeAmount;
        hashToAmount[hash] = 0;
        (bool sent, bytes memory data) = payable(_to).call{value: amount}("");
        require(sent, "Failed to send deposit amount");
        require(sendFees(), "Failed to send fee amount");

        isWithdrawn[hash] = true;

        emit DepositWithdrawn(msg.sender, amount, _to);
    }

    function getUserDeposits() public view returns (Deposit[] memory) {
        Deposit[] memory deposits = addressToDeposits[msg.sender];
        return deposits;
    }

    function setFeeAmount(uint _amount) public onlyOwner {
        feeAmount = _amount;
    }

    function setFeeWallet(address _wallet) public onlyOwner {
        feeWallet = payable(_wallet);
    }

    function sendFees() internal returns (bool) {
        (bool sent, bytes memory data) = payable(feeWallet).call{
            value: feeAmount
        }("");
        return sent;
    }
}
```

Here's the transaction of eth being stolen https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd4f92a3346ff51cf41c40b47b1270eda5ca57c4aaae2b3c9858298d8c6269725

Comment: Its been stolen, you can check the transaction. Also can you please point out some ways I can reduce the gas as well. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I can point out many vulnerabilities that this smart contract has.

One of them is that there is no private data in a smart contract. Anybody can read the data in the storage of a smart contract. In this case, I see that `hashToAmount` has the hashes that you send to the user who created the deposit. But this can be read by anyone (using something like `web3.eth.getStorageAt(contractAddress, storageIndex)`) and call the `withdrawDeposit` function and steal the funds.

Something else, miners can temper with some blockchain data, like the timestamp, etc. Miners can see the `_id` that is being sent to the `createDeposit` and use it to immediately steal the funds from the contract.

Also, I see a lack of checks in the `withdrawDeposit` function.

I suggest that you use well known patterns and modifiers and other checks. Relying more on things like `msg.sender` since nobody can fake or tamper with `msg.sender` value. The `sender` is always the user that created the request, and if the `sender` is the owner of some ether, than only they can withdraw it.

Instead of checking the balance of that hash, save the `msg.sender` in the mapping instead when someone makes a deposit. Then, while withdrawing, check that the `msg.sender` has balance and if so, send the balance to the `_to` address.

Also, check for reentrancy attacks in your `withdrawDeposit` deposit function.

Trying to generate an id in a smart contract with the block data is not that secure. There are oracle libraries that can help you get a pseudo-random number from outside of the contract, but again, it can be read by a miner before the transaction is included in a block and compromise your funds.

I'm not sure if any of these are causing your problem exactly, but I'm sure that all of these could be potential issues for your contract.

I recommend you follow security standard patterns like from OpenZeppelin: https://www.openzeppelin.com/.

Comment: Hello, I know that its not safe to use this method to create random numbers but I have learnt that it is expensive to generat random numbers through an oracle as it uses link.